# Convertir respuesta AJAX en array tipo Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un array llamado `eventDates`, al cual quiero agregarle fechas de tipo `Date`. Las fechas las cojo de una llamada a una base de datos, pero no se como incluirlas al array en tipo Dates.

> Este es el script:

```
var eventDates = {};

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'controller/reservas/reservasControllerMostrarFechasReservas.php',
  success: function (res) {
    eventDates= res;
  }
});
```

> Este es la parte PHP:

```
$consulta = 'SELECT fecha_reserva FROM reservas';

$fecha = parent::query($consulta);

$arrayFechas = array();

while ($fechas = mysqli_fetch_array($fecha)){
  $arrayFechas[] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($fechas['fecha_reserva']));
}

$verificar_fechas = parent::verificarRegistros($consulta);

for($i=0; $i<$verificar_fechas; $i++){
  echo $arrayFechas[$i];
}
```

Lo que quiero es que al final  quede como si hiciera esto pero con las fechas que cojo el AJAX:

```
var eventDates = {};
eventDates[ new Date( '08/07/2018' )] = new Date( '08/07/2018' );
eventDates[ new Date( '08/12/2018' )] = new Date( '08/12/2018' );
eventDates[ new Date( '08/18/2018' )] = new Date( '08/18/2018' );
eventDates[ new Date( '08/23/2018' )] = new Date( '08/23/2018' );
```

Comment: La pregunta es, sabes como agregar un nuevo elemento a un `array`, o no sabes como convertir el `string` que te llega a tipo `Date`

Comment: He modificado el código y ya paso el array desde PHP de tipo Date, y se lo he agregado al array "arrayFechas". Aparte por lo que leido en otros problemas parecidos, se debe inlcuir en el AJAX la opción de "dataType: 'json' para que se pueda insertar un objeto de PHP a JavaScript. El error que me esta dando ahora es que me sale indefinido.

Comment: Prueba en la callback success del ajax hacer un console.log(res) y dinos cual es el resultado de eso para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No sale nada, pero si quito el dataType: 'json' me salen todas las fechas:
03/31/201803/24/201803/24/201803/31/201803/31/201803/24/201803/24/201803/23/201803/24/201803/30/201803/31/201803/23/201803/23/201803/23/201803/23/201803/30/201803/30/201803/30/201803/31/201803/22/201803/22/201803/29/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me respondo a mi mismo, ya que he encontrado una solución, y por si le sirve a alguien aquí lo dejo:

> Script

```
// Definimos el array de las fechas
    var eventDates = [];

// Señalamos en el datepicker los días en los que hay alguna reserva realizada (en el CSS es la clase "event a")
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'controller/reservas/reservasControllerMostrarFechasReservas.php',
  success: function (res) {

    arrayRespuesta = res.split("-");

    for(i=0; i<arrayRespuesta.length; i++){
      eventDates[new Date (arrayRespuesta[i])] = new Date (arrayRespuesta[i]);
    }

    return eventDates;
  }
});

// datepicker
$('#inputFechaReserva').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
      var highlight = eventDates[date];
      if( highlight ) {
            return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
      } else {
            return [true, '', ''];
      }
    }
});
```

});

> Parte PHP

```
$consulta = 'SELECT fecha_reserva FROM reservas';
$fecha = parent::query($consulta);

$verificar_fechas = parent::verificarRegistros($consulta);

while ($fechas = mysqli_fetch_array($fecha)){
  echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($fechas['fecha_reserva']));

  if($verificar_fechas > 1){
    echo "-";
    $verificar_fechas = $verificar_fechas - 1;
  }
}
```